# Where can I set the title of my module's layout tab(s)?

Tags: module, publish-layout

I've got a custom module, with a layout tab, with several fields in it, and that all works fine.
The title of the tab, however, is the lower case module name, and I don't seem to be able to change that.

I've got a lang.*.php file in my language/english directory, and a matching lower case module name field (as in the [download module example](https://github.com/EllisLab/ee-tuts-download-module) - which gets its tab title from the eponymous 'download' key in the lang file).

Any ideas?

Comment: In the language file, can you see the index "[module_name]_module_name", you can change it's value.

Comment: Hi Bhashkar - that doesn't seem to make any difference. I've tried changing the value of both the '{module}_module_name' and the '{module}' keys in the lang file, but it still just displays the lowercase form of the module name.

Comment: May be this tab is being added from Edit/Publish page with the toolbar. The tabs are being saved into database table "exp_layout_publish" but settings is being saved into "field_layout" column in serialize data based on member group. You can search the name by finding "_tab_label" and change its value within database table "exp_layout_publish".

Comment: Hmmm - my `exp_layout_publish` table seems to be empty... 0 entries. Is there anything else that you think this could be?!

Comment: ok, lets do some trick. Just create a new tab (later you can delete it) and click on "Save layout". Now you can see that tab in Edit/Publish entry page. Now you will see the data within table "exp_layout_publish". Just update the name of your desired tab as I told in my previous comment. Once its done, delete the newly created table from the toolbar of Edit/Publish entry page.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor for the tab.module_name.php call your language file and that should look for the tab shortname/key in your lang file.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->EE =& get_instance();
    $this->EE->lang->loadfile('my_lang_file');
}
```

Take a look at how Bjørn Børresen allows for config overrides [on the SEO Lite module](https://github.com/bjornbjorn/SEO-Lite/blob/master/seo_lite/tab.seo_lite.php) so folks can rename the tab to whatever they want.